# Spark Scala - Data Processing - Computing on previous values

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

How can I achieve data transformations like these in spark.

**`Input:`**

**`startTime, Entity, Index`**

```
- T1, E1, I1
- T1, E1, I2
- T1, E1, I3
```

---

```
- T2, E1, I2
- T2, E1, I3
- T2, E1, I4
```

---

```
- T3, E1, I3
- T3, E1, I4
- T3, E1, I5
```

---

```
- T4, E2, I6
```

**`output:`**

startTime, Entity, Index, endTime

```
- T4, E2, I6, null
```

---

```
- T3, E1, I5, null
- T3, E1, I4, null
- T3, E1, I3, null
```

---

```
- T2, E1, I4, null
- T2, E1, I3, null
- T2, E1, I2, T3
```

---

```
- T1, E1, I3, null
- T1, E1, I2, T3
- T1, E1, I1, T2
```

**`Logic:`**

Please look at entity E2 - It has only one value I6 which does not have any overlap. -> Hence for entity E2, I6 is active and hence no endTime.

---

**`==== T3 ====`**

Now, Going back to entity E1 -> Index I3, I4 and I5 are active since they correspond to max(timestamp) for that specific entity (E1)

Hence all of them have endTime as null.

```
- T3, E1, I5, null
- T3, E1, I4, null
- T3, E1, I3, null
```

**`==== T2 ====`**

Since, I3 and I4 are already present in T3 and the endTime is computed we need to keep same end time which is null.

```
- T2, E1, I4, null
- T2, E1, I3, null
```

Index I2 is not present in T3, So index I2 was not active and it got expired at T3

```
- T2, E1, I2, T3
```

**`==== T1 ====`**

Index I2 and I3 are already present in T2 and hence use the same endTime.

```
- T1, E1, I3, null
- T1, E1, I2, T3
```

Index I1 is not present in T2, so index I1 was not active and it got expired at T2

```
- T1, E1, I1, T2
```

---

I'm new to spark. Can any of you please help?

Comment: If you could add formatting to your question, it would help understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I have formatted.

Comment: `Going back to entity E1 -> Index I3, I4 and I5 are active since they correspond to max(timestamp)` why T3 is the max?

Comment: Because for entity E1 there does not exist timestamp greater than T3. Please note that timestamp T4 is for entity E2.